# visual studio custom workflow after publish requires dettach attach to Sharepoint List

Tags: workflow, visual-studio, custom

we have deployed visual studio workflow and attached to a SharePoint 2013 list. after some changes we do publish it from Visual studio, but changes does not reflects immediately, we need to disassociate it and again associates it to list, then only changes gets reflects. this is normal process ? do we really require to do this way ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug that has been reported at the Visual Studio Feedback Section
[VS Workflow Update Issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779905/sharepoint-2013-workflow-deployment-doenst-update-workflow-definition)

However see the **workarounds section** in the same link which has been provided to overcome this

[Similar Issue at SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286924/sharepoint-2013-visual-studio-workflow-not-updating)

Workaround - Right click on your workflow project > Properties and find the sharepoint tab on the left. Then, under the "pre-deployment command line" paste this command:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq vssphost5.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N 
"vssphost5.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" taskkill /f /im vssphost5.exe
exit 0
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, we will check and let you know